# NameError: global name 'pulse_start' is not defined

Tags: python

In the second while loop i cannot access pulse_start ,i also declared pulse_start as global in first while loop.

```
while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
       global pulse_start
       pulse_start = time.time()
       while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
                       pulse_end = time.time()
                       pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
                       distance = pulse_duration * 17150
```

Comment: Your indentation doesn't look right. All the statements in a `while` should be at the same indentation.

Comment: Just calling `global pulse_start` one time immediately prior to the first while loop should work for you.

Comment: If your input pin is 1 to start with, then your first loop never executes, and therefore never initializes `pulse_start`.